# How to define the specified vector

Tags: matlab

I want to define a vector `y=[sin(1),sin(1/2),...,sin(1/1000)]`.

but I don't know how to do that. I defined

```
for i=1:1000 
    y(i)=sin(1/i); 
end
```

but this does not work.

Comment: Can you please add some error message? Because, generally this piece of code should work, although it's not very efficient as stated in the below answer.

Comment: @HansHirse I mean when I do the above code, I see 1000 vectors but I just want the last vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define the `y` as the following (and initialize to get the better performance):

```
y = zeros(1, 1000);
for i = 1:1000
    y(i) = sin(1/i);
end
```

Also you can do it without `for`:

```
y = sin(1./(1:1000));
```

Comment: Note that the vector in this answer is initialized from the start, and not as you go through the loop. This is a big deal in Matlab, and helps performance.